# Input Number is not initialized when the number is a double

Tags: blazor

I would like to initialize an  with a double.
But it doesn't work if the binded variable has a decimal value different from 0.

Here is an example to illustrate the issue.

````
<label >Test 1</label><br />
<input type="number" min="0" max="360" step="0.1" value="@test1" /><br />
<label>Test 2</label><br />
<input type="number" min="0" max="360" step="0.1" value="@test2" />

```

@code {
    public double test1 = 2.0;
    public double test2 = 3.1;
```
````

As it can be seen in the attached picture, Test 1 is initialized but not Test 2, why?
[image]

I couldn't find the reason of this behaviour.

Thank you

Comment: There's no sensible answer  to your question with the display code.  Please can you add it.

Comment: Are you using @bind or @bind-Value? Can you show your code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the html part of the code 
<label >Test 1</label><br />
<input type="number" min="0" max="360" step="0.1" value="@test1" /><br />
<label>Test 2</label><br />
<input type="number" min="0" max="360" step="0.1" value="@test2" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because of your browser's `Culture` settings.

c# will output the value as `3,1` (current culture settings) but the numeric input expects a `3.1`.
You're probably also getting a warning in the browser console if you have a look (`F12` or `Ctr+Shift+I`)

the solution can be to call this:

```
value="@test2.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)"
```